# Calling an external program from DXL

Tags: external, ibm-doors

Specifically, a perl script. Parameters need to be passed, but nothing needs to be returned.

I've searched the web and the Reference Manual, with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on the operating system you are using. You may ecute a command by using the function

```
void system(string command)
```

on Windows. On Unix, use

```
void system(string command, void childCB(int) [,void parentCB()])
```

Check the DXL Reference Manual, Chapter 10 **Operating system interface** for details. Here is example usage:

```
if (platform=="WIN32")
    system "notepad"
```